# django tables2 export to xlsx: How to set exported filename using FBV?

Tags: django, export, export-to-excel, django-tables2

```
Django==1.11.7
django-tables2==1.10.0
tablib==0.11.2
```

Using function based views, how to set the exported filename?

The tables 2 documentation gives a solution for class based views, but is not clear on function based views:
http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/export.html?highlight=function%20based%20views

It mentions an "export_name", but where does this need to be set?

Trying this:

```
def export_payment_list(request):
    _table = PaymentTable4Export(Payment.objects.all().order_by('-payment_date'))
    RequestConfig(request).configure(_table)

    exporter = TableExport('xlsx', _table)
    return exporter.response('table.{}'.format('xlsx'), filename='my_test')
```

... results in an error:

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
response() got multiple values for argument 'filename'
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: It looks like the first argument of `response()` is the filename. If you want the filename to be `my_test.xlsx`, try `return exporter.response(filename='my_test.xlsx')`

Comment: Correct, works fine using `return exporter.response(filename='my_test.xlsx')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the first argument of `response()` is the filename.

If you want the filename to be `my_test.xlsx`, try:

```
return exporter.response(filename='my_test.xlsx')
```

Comment: For completeness, the API of `TableExport.response()` can be found here: http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#django_tables2.export.TableExport.response